# PHP: Execute command using SSH on remote server without using net_ssh2

Tags: php, ssh

I have a simple code shown below.

```
<?php
    $command = escapeshellcmd('ssh 192.168.0.33 ls');
    $output = shell_exec($command);
    echo $output;
?>
```

When I execute using

```
php ssh_server.php
```

It works. That is, I am able to list all the files.

But When I try accessing it via the web server

```
 localhost:8181/ssh_server.php
```

It does not.

Is there a way out of this. I cannot use net_ssh2 (limitations of server).

Comment: Is the webserver running under your username? If not, it won't use your `$HOME/.ssh` directory to get your SSH settings.

Comment: what authentication do you use? You should give the private key to some place where it will be accessible by the `www-data` user.

Comment: *"It does not."*: That's not very descriptive error report. What does it do instead? Any error message?